# How to check whether ImageMagick is setup correctly on macOS?

Tags: images, environment

I installed emacs on macOS by `brew cask install emacs`. But the functionality of resizing images doesn't work as expected.

So, how to check whether the emacs distribution is built with imagemagick support or not?

And are there any other setup needed?

Answer (score 6):

According to the doc

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/ImageMagick-Images.html

you can check for imagemagick support with `(image-type-available-p 'imagemagick)`

you could use emacs-plus (https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus) which supports imagemagick by default

```
brew tap d12frosted/emacs-plus
brew install emacs-plus --without-spacemacs-icon
```

or build emacs on your own with imagemagick support flag